# Web browser without HDD access

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, chromium, browser-cache

I'm wondering if there is a way to disable *all* browsing-related drive access (history, cookie jar, disk caches) in either Firefox or Google Chromium (Linux).

Basically, I'm running this on a laptop, with wads of RAM, but often enough in an environment that triggers drive head protection - working from cars, working in industrial settings, etc. The continuous spin-up just to take note that I opened another tab.. is both time consuming and annoying (why is it synchronous with my activities in the first place?).

Before I go nuclear on the project and just dump .firefox / .cache on their own tiny ramdisk, any ideas? I think ChromeOS-based laptops do it somehow, but how?

Comment: You could just get an SSD for your laptop, it'd solve a bunch of problems you'd have with using it in those situations. It's pretty hard to make the OS itself not use any disk at all.

Comment: Given that I have it nailed down to the *only* app that actually writes to disk without a direct request.. Getting SSD through our regulatory needs? forget it, at least until degaussers catch up (or someone figures out that perhaps a big shredder is good enough) (Basically I haven't seen an SSD that properly supports secure erase  unit)

Comment: gobs of ram, browser temps stuff ?  ramdisk that you mention would be perfect. just redirect all the net folders to it.  any kind of flash chunk could have the net stuff sent to it, if there is a way in the laptop to stuff in some sort of flash chunk (like PCMIA) or slots for it, without it sticking out ready to be broken off.

Comment: yeah, the ramdisk option is probably optimal - just fishing for information whether browsers can be coerced to behave in a more sane manner (what about old-fashioned 'save session on exit, and don't bother writing in the meantime'?) This is also probably quite critical for HOME on NFS deployments etc.

Comment: Try **Firefox Portable** with a ramdisk. You can then have a super-fast Firefox installation. The only thing is, you'll need to setup two batch files: one to create the ramdisk, copy FF Portable to it and run FF, two to copy out the FF Portable to hard disk (or sync it with **DSynchronize**; faster and better) and destroy the ramdisk.

Comment: Do you happen to know how does FF portable do it? I'm on linux, so I don't care that much about loading times - the OS does a splendid job prefetching and keeping stuff in RAM, and there is no FF portable for linux. One day I toyed around with sticking the entire OS in a compressed ramdisk, but I do development and sometimes need to change the OS itself.

Comment: [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) is for Windows.

Comment: Oh sorry, Firefox Portable (for Windows) can run in Linux under Wine. But if that's not what you want (instead, you wanna run the native Firefox) it can't help you. "Do you happen to know how does FF portable do it?" Firefox portable doesn't load itself into a ramdisk, if that's what you're asking. I was trying to tell you a way you can do that manually. PS: I'll look for ways to make native Linux Firefox portable.

Comment: Yeah, I could put Firefox Portable on a ramdisk (just returned from another of those annoying trips) - but I just went with mountbinding .firefox .cache and .mozilla into a ramdisk, prepopulated on boot - this solved that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried disabling Disk Cache?

- Type `about:config` into the Firefox address bar and press enter.
- Set the value of `browser.cache.disk.enable` to false.
- Create a new integer value named `disk.cache.memory.capacity` and set its value to 32768 (for 32MB), 65536 (for 64MB), etc (MB value x 1024), or -1 to auto-determine.
- Restart Firefox.

For Chromium or Google Chrome, you can redirect the disk cache to a Ramdisk (see second link below).

Here are some sites I found which tell you how to make Firefox use a Ramdisk:

- [archlinux wiki - Firefox Ramdisk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox_Ramdisk)
- [Firefox & Chrome Cache on RAM Drive -Fedora / Ubuntu | LinuxReaders](http://www.linuxreaders.com/2011/01/11/firefox-chrome-cache-on-ram-drive-fedora-ubuntu/)
- [Try Out Linux Programs with PortableLinuxApps - How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24863/try-out-linux-programs-with-portablelinuxapps/) (Not Ramdisk related, but has an *outdated* portable version of Firefox for Linux)

The thing with Linux is that instructions will differ according to the different distro and different version of the distro itself that you use. Commands that work smooth in one distro can be unrecognizable in a different distro (lack of standardization, basically; something that I really hate about Linux). You'll have to try out everything to find what works for you.

Comment: Yeah, but disk cache is not the major problem - Firefox seems to like to record *everything* to permanent memory, and to do so synchronously. History, Cookie jars are the things that mess up it a lot - but basically, conceptually, why is there *no* function to disable writing anything anywhere?